# aws cli cache incorrect location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set up a windows task schedule to trigger a .bat file `upload.bat`.

```
cd C:\working
set AWS_CONFIG_FILE=%USERPROFILE%\.aws\config
set AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials

python upload.py
```

Here is a portion of `upload.py`, it is calling aws s3 cp command.

```
from subprocess import check_call

def upload_file():
    try:
        check_call("aws s3 cp inFile destination --profile myprofile")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print('Error while upload!')
```

The code runs fine, but after execution, there is a new folder `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` generated in the working directory , i.e. `C:\working\%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, inside this folder, there is the aws cli cache `C:\working\%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.aws\cli\cache\xxxxx.json`, why is this cache not generated in my user's home directory? Instead it has generated a new folder in the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

It goes to `homedir` only when you assume the role as per [this code here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/5aa599949f60b6af554fd5714d7161aa272716f7/awscli/customizations/assumerole.py#L8) in `awscli`

```py
CACHE_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.aws', 'cli', 'cache'))
```

similar is the case for `boto` as well [this code here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/88d780dea1684da00689f2eef388fa4c782ced08/botocore/credentials.py#L249)

```py
CACHE_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.aws', 'cli', 'cache'))
```

[Configuration and credential file settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-settings)

> When you use a shared profile that specifies an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role, the AWS CLI calls the AWS STS AssumeRole operation to retrieve temporary credentials. These credentials are then stored (in ~/.aws/cli/cache). Subsequent AWS CLI commands use the cached temporary credentials until they expire, and at that point, the AWS CLI automatically refreshes the credentials.